# Ошибка при миграции: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Добрая ночь. Основная цель - это возможность полноценной работы ASP.Identity core в проекте под ASP.NET CORE + WEB API. Хотел сделать миграцию перед возможностью использования встроенной модели хранения пользователей в Identity, но получилась ошибка object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Подробнее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Startup.cs:**

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                  {
                      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                      {
                          // укзывает, будет ли валидироваться издатель при валидации токена
                          ValidateIssuer = true,
                          // строка, представляющая издателя
                          ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,

                          // будет ли валидироваться потребитель токена
                          ValidateAudience = true,
                          // установка потребителя токена
                          ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                          // будет ли валидироваться время существования
                          ValidateLifetime = true,

                          // установка ключа безопасности
                          IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                          // валидация ключа безопасности
                          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                      };
                  });

            services.AddMvc();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [En SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38437958/6808809). В двух словах "Убедитесь, что в папке с проектом есть .config файл" или "попробуйте выбрать проект по умолчанию"

Comment: Если вы пишете проект `ASP.NET CORE` то надо использовать `Entity Framework CORE`, а не как у вас `Entity Framework 6.2.0`

Comment: @Bulson спасибо. Помогло удаление Entity Framework 6.2.0. До этого у меня был установлен Entity Framework CORE, видно среда видела EF 6.2.0 только либо был какой-то конфликт между ними

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ответ ~